# Network installation giving errors when viewing or adding a user

Tags: php, multisite, users

I have just installed a fresh version of WP which I have turned in to a network install (using the instructions found [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network)).

All seemed to be going well, and I was able to add a new site successfully, however I am experiencing issues with listing/adding users.

When I click on the `Users` menu item the list table gives the following warning -

> Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in {my-dir}\wp-admin\includes\class-wp-users-list-table.php on line 307

This line is - `$editable_roles = array_keys( get_editable_roles() );` - the issue is that `get_editable_roles()` is ruturning `false`.

The same problem also occurs when I try to add a user, although the warning is at a different location -

> Warning: array_reverse() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in {my-dir}\wp-admin\includes\template.php on line 843

I've tried the obvious, deactivating all plugins (I'd added one) and switching to the default theme, but the warnings still remain.

Looking at `get_editable_roles()` I can see that the global `$wp_roles->roles` is empty, although `$wp_roles->role_objects` is correctly populated.  From here, I don't really know where to go next.

Can anybody please suggest how I may fix this problem?

Comment: Which plugin did you installed? I heard about some plugins be responsible of this error. Try to make the fresh install again without installing any plugin.

Comment: It was a custom plugin that creates a new post type and two new taxonomies (I wish to use this on multiple instances within the network, hence the need for a plugin rather than it being within a theme/child theme). No posts or terms had been created using them though, and sadly disabling it made no diference. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the DB, the `wp_user_roles` option in `wp_options` was empty. I copied the value from the same option in `wp_2_options`, as I had already added another blog.

Also, every user from the original blog (it was up and running before being changed to a network) had nothing listed against both the `wp_capabilities` and `wp_user_level` options in `wp_usermeta`. Because of this, the `get_editable_roles()` function was failing and in turn causing the errors listed above.

To fix this problem, for each user on the original blog, I copied the entries for the relevant user levels from the data stored under `wp_2_capabilities` and `wp_2_user_level`.

Comment: I have the same issue and can't figure out how to fix it. I have checked my `wp_x_options` tables and they have values set for `wp_x_user_roles` row. And my `wp_usermeta` table has a `wp_capabilities` row for most users. I need to dig deeper into the schema to see exactly how it fits together.

Comment: Trick for me was renaming the wp_user_roles to wp_x_user_roles - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11725/why-are-my-roles-not-visible-in-a-multi-site-network#answer-23471