# Multisite network admin - User's role not showing up

Tags: multisite, user-roles, upgrade

I upgrade my wordpress to 4.7.1 two days ago, then i am having trouble with my roles in the multisite admin. My issue is similar with this one, where the roles are not visible in my multi-site admin panel.
[Why are my roles not visible in a Multi-site/Network?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11725/why-are-my-roles-not-visible-in-a-multi-site-network)

But the wp_##_options' table was alright in my database, so their solution does not work for me.

In my case, the roles are correct in https://www.exampleblog.com/wp-admin/user-new.php. See below image.
[image]

But it does not show up in my multi-site admin interface. See below image.
[image]
The URL for this interface on my site is :https://www.exampleblog.com/wp-admin/network/site-users.php

In addition, the roles are not listed at the User information table either. See below image: [image]

Am i missing something? Any hints? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

Make sure the row in option-table in the database for wordpress-site have the correct option_name for the serialised roles-data.

For instance;
if the database-table is wp_options, the column option_name in the role-row should be wp_user_roles.
if the database-table is wp_20_options, the column option_name in the role-row should be wp_20_user_roles.

Don't ask me how long it took me to find out.

Hope it helps.

Comment: hey, thanks for answering. but the name are fine in my database. i checked several blogs, they are all correct. :(

Comment: I had duplicated rows, one `wp_user_roles` and another `wp_XX_user_roles`